# What does "thought to" mean here?

Tags: meaning

> All I could think through the whole day was that we missed my brother’s football game because of me, and I really hoped my sister **thought to** tape it.
>
> —The Perks of Being a Wallflower

It looks like it meant "remembered to". But is this a usual usage with the word? Can someone point me out a legit source for this definition?

Comment: I agree with you about the meaning: [think to do something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/think) ~ to remember someone or something. I couldn't say for sure about it being usually used. However, I remember that that line surprised me a little too when I watched the movie.

Comment: "thought to", here = paid attention and took an action [ which the action is filming the game.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a very common usage.

**To think to do something** - Have sufficient foresight or awareness to do something.

**Example -**

> I hadn't thought to warn Rachel about him.

**Now your sentence -**

> I really hoped my sister thought to tape it.

This means that I hoped my sister had a sufficient insight before/during the match to record his brother's football match.

Answer (score 0):

I think the catch is *to* which is used after the word *thought* because what preposition the word *thought* takes changes its meaning. *Thought to* is different than *Thought of*, isn't it?

Okay, I think *thought to [something]* in this context means *consider that thing*

> [thought (n) (#5)](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thought) -**Consideration;** attention.

So,

> I really hoped my sister **thought to tape it** - He really hopes that his sister could have considered shooting his game so that he could watch it and not miss it.

Comment: Your #5 is for "thought" as a noun.